# picketInput change placeholder R Shiny Widgets

Tags: css, r, shiny, placeholder, shinywidgets

`pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets` package has a placeholder title `Nothing selected`.

How is it possible to replace it with `Pick a choice` for example ? I would prefer a solution that uses css or the options of `pickerInput`, if possible avoid `shinyjs`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("

    "))
  ),

  pickerInput(
    inputId = "mtcInputIndicateur", 
    label = "Select values", 
    choices = paste("choice", 1:10),
    options = list(`live-search` = TRUE),
    multiple = TRUE
  )
)



server <- function(input, output){
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer, use the parameter `title` in `options`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

  pickerInput(
    inputId = "mtcInputIndicateur", 
    label = "Select values", 
    choices = paste("choice", 1:10),
    options = list(`live-search` = TRUE, title = "Pick a choice"),
    multiple = TRUE
  )
)



server <- function(input, output){
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does this solution not work with `updatePickerInput`? I am trying to change the placeholder when user clicks the search button by using `observeEvent`, but this doesn't seem to work on my end..

Comment: I think you should place `pickerInput` inside `renderUI` function in `server` with a `uiOutput` in `ui`